# internal socket & external socket together with tcp

Tags: c, sockets

I have a server in c language which accepts via select requests from clients.  I create some threads to serve the requested actions from clients. Until this point i am ok. But now i want to have an internal socket, so the created threads will communicate with the main thread, to send their response through this. Any ideas how to fix all this?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy.  What you want to use for this is `socketpair(2)`.   Create one pair for each thread and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

@Guillaume is right. But why go through all that complexity.

I would only do this if you intend to have a server that sometimes runs with all the threads in one program communicating through sockets and sometimes runs on different computers with 'worker thread servers' that communicate over regular sockets.

Unless you need to have something exotic like this, you can just communicate between threads with a block of shared memory (protected with mutexes as appropriate). E.g. pass task objects from dispatcher thread to worker threads. And forget about the complexity of serializing and unserializing data for communication between threads.

Comment: i know that a share memory would be an easier idea, but unfortunately i want to make it work with such an "exotic" way. so i will try to find the way with Guillaume's way. thanks a lot btw.

Comment: It depends.  If the work dispatch mechanism is already built on sockets, it's definitely easier to use sockets.  If you switch a shared memory queue, you'll have to poll the socket in one call, and your queues in another.You could do the notification using sockets (write one byte) but do the actual communication over shared memory.  Depending on how much stuff is exchanged, it might be a good trade off